# Changing a text color by javascript without changing its :hover color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this css :

```
.overlay-left-a {
  color:red;
}
.overlay-left-a:hover {
  color:black;
}
```

And this javascript :

```
let gr1 = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay-left-a");
for (let i = 0; i < gr1.length; i++) {
  gr1[i].style.color = blue;
}
```

But I wish my javascript don't change the ':hover' color.

What is please the best way ?

Comment: do u have multiple elements and want to change thier font color?

Comment: Yes, I wish to change all colors through javascript (but not the :hover one)

Answer (score 2):

Use another class, not inline styles, that uses `:not(:hover)` to say not to apply it to hovered elements. (`:not` is the [negation-pseudo class](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#negation), which you can put a [*simple* selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#simple-selectors-dfn) inside.)

```css
.overlay-left-a.blue:not(:hover) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=button]").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.currentTarget.disabled = true;
    let gr1 = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay-left-a");
    for (let i = 0; i < gr1.length; i++) {
        gr1[i].classList.add("blue");
    }
});
```

```css
.overlay-left-a {
  color:red;
}
.overlay-left-a:hover {
  color:black;
}
.overlay-left-a.blue:not(:hover) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay-left-a">hover me</div>
<input type="button" value="Click To Change Color To Blue">
```

---

In a comment you've indicated that the color is provided dynamically, so the above won't work for your specific situation.

To do that, you can use a CSS variable [as mmh4all shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71524869/157247). If you can't use a CSS variable for some reason (obsolete browsers or something), you can add a `style` element to your page:

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=button]").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    // Get the color
    const color = document.getElementById("txt-color").value.trim();

    // Create or update a style element applying that color
    // to `.overlay-left-a` elements
    let style = document.getElementById("overlay-left-a-color");
    if (!style) {
        style = document.createElement("style");
        style.id = "overlay-left-a-color";
        document.querySelector("head").appendChild(style);
    }
    style.textContent = `.overlay-left-a:not(:hover) { color: ${color}; }`;
});
```

```css
.overlay-left-a {
  color:red;
}
.overlay-left-a:hover {
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay-left-a">hover me</div>
<label>
    Color name: <input type="text" id="txt-color" value="blue">
</label>
<input type="button" value="Set Color">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that perfectly works, it would be an excellent solution for a lot of people, but in my case, the 'blue', in javascript, was only a sample. In fact, a color will be given by a fetch(), several times, depending of the user behaviour.

Comment: @amir - I've updated the answer to add a dynamic alternative.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you can do it like this: Change a CSS variable without overriding the hover color. The main part is this CSS:

```css
:root {
    --color: red;
}
.overlay-left-a {
    color: var(--color);
}
```

Then you can change the value of the color on `:root` like this:

```js
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--color", "blue");
//                                    Or whatever −−−−^^^^^^
```

Live Example:

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=button]").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    // Get the color
    const color = document.getElementById("txt-color").value.trim();

    // Apply it
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--color", color);
});
```

```css
:root {
    --color: red;
}

.overlay-left-a {
    color: var(--color);
}

.overlay-left-a:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="overlay-left-a">test</a>
<a href="" class="overlay-left-a">test</a>
<a href="" class="overlay-left-a">test</a>
<a href="" class="overlay-left-a">test</a>
<div>
    <label>
        Color name: <input type="text" id="txt-color" value="blue">
    </label>
    <input type="button" value="Set Color">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I really need to do it through javascript.

Comment: @amir the first line is javascript, provide me with more details about ur code so i can update my solution, do u want to change the color whenever u click the links?

Comment: 'blue', in javascript, was only for the sample. In fact, a color (decided by the server) will be given by a fetch(), several times during the website visit, depending of the user behaviour. Is ti enough, for details ?

Comment: @amir - Then you'd just use that color instead of `"blue"` in the JavaScript.

Comment: Nice answer! I always forget about CSS "variables."

Comment: But please do write out entire words ("your", "you") rather than using text-speak, and a bit more explanation would generally be best. I've updated the answer to do that, and to demonstrate that this can be entirely dynamic.